# Finite Fields: check my description/derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, proof-verification, finite-fields

I am preparing for my exam in Advanced Algebra and Galois Theory, and I am trying to find an efficient way to communicate main properties of Finite Fields. If someone could check my approach and comment I would be most grateful!

### Finite Fields

Let $F$ be a field with $q>1$ elements. Since the field is finite it must have finite characteristic:
$$
\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_p=0
$$
Now $p$ has to be a prime number for otherwise $p=a\cdot b=0$ would make $a$ and $b$ zero divisors which is a contradiction to have in a field.

Clearly $\newcommand{\Zp}{\mathbb{Z}_p}\Zp$ can be isomorhpically embedded in $F$ so we have a finite field extension $F\supset\Zp$ which then must have a basis $v_1,...,v_n\in F$ so that any $\alpha\in F$ can be expressed uniquely as
$$
\alpha=a_1\cdot v_1+...+a_n\cdot v_n
$$
with coefficients $a_i\in\Zp$. This shows that $F$ has $q=p^n$ elements.

### Edited reading Dustan Levenstein's answer

Now since the multiplicative group $F^*$ has $p^n-1$ elements and we know that an element of a group raised to the order of the entire group yields the neutral element we have that all elements of $F^*$ satisfies
$$
X^{p^n-1}-1=0
$$
or just as well after multiplying by $X$ that $X^q-X=0$. This shows that $F$ can be embedded as
$$
F\subseteq \mbox{split}(X^q-X,\Zp)
$$
in the splitting field of $X^q-X$ over $\Zp$.

Since $(X^q-X)'=qX^{q-1}-1=-1$ (using that $q=p^n=0$ in characteristic $p$) we see that $X^q-X$ has no multiple roots. Furtermore the roots form a field since we know that $(\alpha+\beta)^q=\alpha^q+\beta^q$ in characteristic $p$ so that
$$
(\alpha+\beta)^q-(\alpha+\beta)=(\alpha^q-\alpha)+(\beta^q-\beta)=0+0=0
$$
for roots $\alpha,\beta$ of $X^q-X$. Furthermore, if $\alpha,\beta$ are roots we can either have one of them zero and then $\alpha\beta=0$ will be a root as well. Suppose they are both non-zero. Then they must be a root of $X^{q-1}-1$ so $q-1$'th roots of unity. These are closed under multiplication (it is the multiplicative group of $F$).

All this shows that $X^q-X$ is a separable polynomial over $\Zp$ and that the splitting field has $q$ elements. Thus we must have
$$
F\simeq \mbox{split}(X^q-X,\Zp)
$$

I hope this is it!

Comment: $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p^n$ as *what*? As a group and as a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-vector space, yes. As a ring, no!

Comment: $F \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(X^n)$ is absolutely wrong. Think about it.

Comment: There is no need to talk about isomorphisms at this point, the point is that $F$ is a finite vector space over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, and so it has $p^k$ elements for some integer $k$.

Comment: You just need an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, not $X^n$.  (In practice it's good if it's also *primitive*, meaning its root generates the multiplicative group of the extension.)

Comment: Splitting field of $X^q-X$ is the standard construction. I don't know of a way to prove that irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ exist other than via the construction of the field extension as a splitting field first.

Comment: Generally, most expositions of finite fields proceed roughly like this. 1) Show that a finite field must have $p^k$ elements for some prime $p$ and integer $k$, this is what you have done here. 2) Show that a finite field must be a field extension $\mathbf{Z}_p(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of some irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}_p$ (this is the primitive element theorem). 3) Show that irreducible polynomials of any degree exist, i.e. there is a finite field with $p^n$ elements for all $p$ and all $n$. 4) Show that two finite fields of same order are isomorphic.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Ah, it is slowly comming back to me. Is this because the multiplicative group has $p^n-1$ elements so that any element of that group is a root of $X^{p^n-1}-1$ or just as well $X^{p^n}-X$ if you prefer? And since $X^{p^n-1}-1$ is irr. over $\Zp$ (haven't thought that through yet) so the roots must live in a larger field - the splitting field...

Comment: And as @DustanLevenstein said, 3) uses the construction of the finite field with $q = p^n$ elements as the splitting field of $X^q - X$.

Comment: $X^{q-1}-1$ is almost never irreducible; you have to construct the splitting field, which involves adjoining roots for all irreducible factors in a systematic way.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: But how will I ever know that the number of elements is correct? Or put differently, how can I be sure that $F$ is isomorphic to the said splitting field, what does it take?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: You mean that for $p$ odd we have $q=2k+1$ odd so that $$X^{q-1}=(X^k+1)(X^k-1)$$ and then some?

Comment: @String Just take any general algebra textbook, and it will give you the whole process I outlined above. (There are probably also some kind of lecture notes you can find online which do it.)

Comment: I think you already saw above why $F$ has to consist of roots of $X^q-X$, and it must be all of the roots just by counting. So $F$ is certainly a splitting field of $X^q-X$, and all splitting fields are isomorphic (you should take a crack at proving that if you haven't already). This proves uniqueness up to isomorphism. For existence, you need to prove that the splitting field of $X^q-X$ does indeed consist of exactly $q$ elements. Why can't it have fewer than $q$ elements? Why can't it have more than $q$ elements?

Comment: @fkraiem: Both of which I lack. My textbook does it without knowing about splitting fields, and the derivation is very long and on a much lower level than what I know (or is supposed to know) by now. The advanced textbook does not cover it and my lecturer gave no notes on it. Maybe one of the other students or an internet site has it. But of course I can do the research myself!

Comment: @String What textbook is that, out of curiosity?

Comment: and in answer to your question about factoring, note that $1$ is a root of $X^{q-1}-1$. So unless $q=2$, the polynomial will not be irreducible.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: The Galois notes are "Advanced Algebra" by Jens Carsten Jantzen, Aarhus University, June 2005. The abstract algebra textbook prior to these notes was "Concrete Abstract Algebra" by Niels Lauritzen, Cambridge University Press 2003 (reprinted 2005).

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Is it because $X^q-X$ has at most $q$ distinct roots and that all $q$ elements of $F$ are roots. If that is correct it seems I managed to get there. Thanks to all of you for your time in any case!!!

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: I did the proof that splitting fields are isomorphic, but I have to run over it again as I found it a bit technical at some points. I am almost there on that one, though.

Comment: The existence part is subtle: to prove that the splitting field contains at least $q$ elements, show that no two roots of $X^q-X$ can be the same (that is, $X^q-X$ is a _separable_ polynomial). To show that the splitting field contains no more than $q$ elements, show that the roots of $X^q-X$ themselves form the elements of a field, i.e., in particular that they are closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Ah, ok: I was only considering $F$ as some finite field that already existed, but of course it is also important to know, that all finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ with $p^n$ elements do exist!

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: If you make any of your comments an answer and state it as a hint, I will most certainly choose your answer as best! I feel you are slowly massaging sense into my head with your comments so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments:

The theorem is that for each prime $p$ and natural number $n \ge 1$, there exists a unique field, up to isomorphism, of order $q = p^n$. You've already shown that every finite field must have order equal to such a $q$.

To prove uniqueness, assume $F$ is a field of order $q$, and prove that $F$ consists of exactly the roots of $X^q-X$. Therefore it must be a splitting field over $\mathbb F_p$ of $X^q-X$, and splitting fields are unique up to isomorphism.

To prove existence, you need to show that the splitting field over $\mathbb F_p$ of $X^q-X$ consits of exactly $q$ elements. That it contains no fewer follows from $X^q-X$ having no multiple roots, i.e. $X^q-X$ is separable. To show it contains no more than $q$ elements, prove that the roots of $X^q-X$ themselves form a field; this consists primarily of showing that they are closed under addition and multiplication.